The shortest way from A1 to B1
On the square A1 of a regular chessboard is a regular dice, face 1 up and face 2 in front. The only allowed move is to rotate the dice by 90 degrees to an adjacent square.
Find the shortest way from A1 to B1 so that the dice ends in the same orientation (face 1 up and face 2 in front).
Inspired by  https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/js/cube.html

Have you by any chance played a game called "The Last Cube"?  Puzzles similar to this are a major part of that game.

The shortest way from A1 to B1 is:

 actually impossible. There is a parity constraint that prohibits the cube from being in the same orientation as the start when it arrives at B1.

 A simple way to see this by marking the grid points where the edges of the squares meet as shown below, as well as four of the cube's corners. As the cube rolls, its marked corners are always on the marked grid points. In the goal position this is not the case, so the goal is not possible.


